# Caching pip packages in requirements.txt using vercel.json

Tags: python, flask, pip, serverless, vercel

Whenever I am deploying to Vercel, it takes 10+ minutes to install pip packages.
I am digging into Vercel documentation, I cannot locate any caching pip packages articles. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.3.3
Flask-Admin==1.6.1
Flask-BabelEx==0.9.4
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==4.0.5
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.10
Flask-Security-Too==5.3.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.1.1
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api/app" }
  ]
}
```